# Limit amount of echoed Ajax reply from an XML file

Tags: javascript, php, ajax, xml, search

I'm creating an AJAX-XML-PHP Search enginge, and found a brilliant article on w3schools: [here](https://www.w3schools.com/PhP/php_ajax_livesearch.asp), however my XML file is huge, and it makes the page also super long to scroll down on whenever one or two letters is typed.  What I would want to happen, is for the php file to only reply 6 'possible searches' if you get what I mean. Here is my code:

```
<?php
$xmlDoc=new DOMDocument();
$xmlDoc->load("places.xml");

$x=$xmlDoc->getElementsByTagName('link');

//get the q parameter from URL
$q=$_GET["q"];

$counter;

//lookup all links from the xml file if length of q>0
if (strlen($q)>0) {
  $hint="";
  for($i=0; $i<($x->length); $i++) {
    $y=$x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('title'); //$y = title
    $z=$x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('url');   //$z = url
      if ($y->item(0)->nodeType==1) {
      //find a link matching the search text
      if (stristr($y->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue,$q)) {
        if ($hint=="") {
          $hint="<a href='" . $z->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue . "' target='_blank'>" . $y->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue . "</a>";
        } else {
          $hint=$hint . "<br /><a href='" . $z->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue . "' target='_blank'>" . $y->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue . "</a>";
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
// Set output to "no suggestion" if no hint was found
// or to the correct values
if ($hint=="") {
  $response="Hmm, nothing here!";
} else {
  $response=$hint;
}

//output the response
echo $response;
?>
```

and here is a snippet of my XML file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?><places><link><title>Afghanistan</title><url>/places/Afghanistan</url></link><link><title>Albania</title><url>/places/Albania</url></link>
```

of course ending with `</places>`.

I have been struggling with this task for around 2 days and any support would really help!

**Note: the Ajax is working fine, so is the Client side html+js, its just getting 6 replies that I can't do!**

Comment: `for($i=0; $i<6; $i++) {` ?

Comment: @SergeK. Unfortunately, I have tried that already, and for some reason it only lists the first 6 XML nodes :/

Comment: From what I understand, you only need 6 results..

Comment: @TamirNahum yes, but it will only list 6 of my hundres of xml nodes

Comment: So what do you want it to do? You said you want only 6 results from those hundreds...

Comment: @TamirNahum I should have made that more clear, sorry. What happens when I use that code, is it will list the first six XML nodes from my document, nothing else. If I type in the <title> of another node, that the script doesn't list, it simply wont appear which is not want I wanted.

Answer (score 2):

take a count of the 'good' items and then check against that

```
$minimumQLength = 4;
if (strlen($q)>$minimumQLength) {
    for($i=0; $i<($x->length); $i++) {
      if($hintcount<6){
        $y=$x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('title'); //$y = title
         $z=$x->item($i)->getElementsByTagName('url');   //$z = url
          if ($y->item(0)->nodeType==1) {
             //find a link matching the search text
             if (stristr($y->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue,$q)) {
                $hintcount++;
                if ($hint=="") {
                   $hint="<a href='" . $z->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue . "' target='_blank'>" . $y->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue . "</a>";
                } else {
                   $hint=$hint . "<br /><a href='" . $z->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue . "' target='_blank'>" . $y->item(0)->childNodes->item(0)->nodeValue . "</a>";
                }
             }
          }
     }
     else{
        break;
     }
   }
}
```

EDIT: added $minimumQLength variable - use that to require longer queries.

Comment: Works great, however, if I were to type "g", for example, it would list all of the "a's" that have a g in.

Comment: Seems you have other rules about these '6' that aren't very clear......  You said you wanted to return only 6 'winners' - and that would include all of the "a's" that have a 'g' in it (because your search rules state that).  If you need to further limit returns, you might want to make a rule about the length of 'q' or something else.